# Spring Security filter for any URL

Tags: spring-security

I have a requirement as below

1. User makes a request to access welcome.html. In the process of request, we are also posting  userid.
2. Once the request reaches to the server, first think  i need to check if user present in my DB or not, in case it is not present, then i have to redirect to the login page and incase user is already present in my db, need to create new session and redirect to welcome.html.

I am not sure, how can I achieve this functionality.

Looking for some idea.

thanks

Adi

Comment: Doesn't this mean that anyone can bypass authentication by posting a userId to the system? Also, if they aren't present in the DB, what is the point in sending them to a login page, since there is no information to authenticate them?

Comment: OK think in other way, before i redirect the welcome page, i need to store user credential in my system along with Active directory  validation.